# ExtJs populating values in timefields

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am learning ExtJs, and I have a form gridpanel with `timefield`s that I want to populate with JSON data pulled from database.

This is the data I'm storing:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'employeeStore',
    fields:['id', 'app_name', 'open_datetime', 'close_datetime', 'holiday_desc'],
    data:[
        {id:1, app_name:"A", open_datetime:"08:00", close_datetime:"09:00", holiday_desc:"ADay"},
        {id:2, app_name:"B", open_datetime:"00:00", close_datetime:"23:59", holiday_desc:" BDay"}

    ]
});
```

Now I have `timefield`s in my form, and I want to populate `openTime`, `closeTime` fields with the data `open_datetime` and `close_datetime` that I stored.

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      width: 300,
      bodyPadding: 10,
      title: 'getters and setters',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'datemenu',
        floating: false,
        height: 210,
        id: 'datePickerMenu',
        width: 240
      }, {
        xtype: 'text',
        text: 'openTime',
        margin: '5px',
        id: 'open',
        dataIndex: 'open_datetime'
      }, {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        style: {
          margin: '5px'
        }
      }, {
        xtype: 'text',
        text: 'closeTime',
        margin: '5px'
      }, {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        style: {
          margin: '5px'
        }
      }, {
        xtype: 'text',
        text: 'Message',
        margin: '5px'

      }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        style: {
          margin: '5px'
        }
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

Now, how do I show the data in the `timefield`s? Should I show the data with data_Index when using columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you can go about this, and depending on the version of Ext JS that you're using, there might only be one.  I'm assuming you're using at least v5.  The other thing I'm assuming is that you have a grid with your store, as it wouldn't make sense to have a form loading two records... it wouldn't know which record to use for its form values.

Also, I think it's a good practice to avoid using the `id` field, especially if you're creating a form... what if you wanted to use that form twice in the same view?  You wouldn't be able to because you would have two identical ids.  Instead, you might want to use [`itemId`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-itemId) or [`reference`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Bindable-cfg-reference).

Here is an example I came up with:

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      fields: ['id', 'app_name', 'open_datetime', 'close_datetime', 'holiday_desc'],
      data: [{
          id: 1,
          app_name: "A",
          open_datetime: "08:00",
          close_datetime: "09:00",
          holiday_desc: "ADay"
        }, {
          id: 2,
          app_name: "B",
          open_datetime: "00:00",
          close_datetime: "23:59",
          holiday_desc: " BDay"
        }

      ]
    });
    var first = store.first();
    var second = store.getAt(1);
    /* Non-Bound Form... this doesn't use model binding,
     * but it uses the Name property, which relies on loading
     * the form with a record */
    Ext.define('My.Non.Bound.Form', {
      extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
      bodyPadding: 10,
      title: 'Non-Bound Form: getters and setters',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'datemenu',
        floating: false
      }, {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Open Time',
        name: 'open_datetime',
        margin: 5
      }, {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Close Time',
        margin: 5,
        name: 'close_datetime'
      }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        text: 'Message',
        margin: '5px'

      }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        style: {
          margin: '5px'
        }
      }]
    });
    /* Bound Form... this makes use of ViewModel binding,
     * so that means you must supply a ViewModel, and its
     * data with a currentRecord property... this has many
     * added benefits... I encourage you to read https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html */
    Ext.define('My.Bound.Form', {
      extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
      bodyPadding: 10,
      title: 'Bound Form: getters and setters',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'datemenu',
        floating: false
      }, {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Open Time',
        margin: 5,
        bind: {
          value: '{currentRecord.open_datetime}'
        }
      }, {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Close Time',
        margin: 5,
        bind: {
          value: '{currentRecord.close_datetime}'
        }
      }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        text: 'Message',
        margin: '5px'

      }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        style: {
          margin: '5px'
        }
      }]
    });
    var myNonBoundForm = Ext.create('My.Non.Bound.Form'); // render plain form approach
    myNonBoundForm.loadRecord(first);
    var myBoundForm = Ext.create('My.Bound.Form', {
      viewModel: {
        data: {
          currentRecord: second
        }
      }
    });
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
      },
      defaults: {
        flex: 1
      },
      items: [myNonBoundForm, myBoundForm]
    })
  }
});
```

In this example, I show you two ways of loading your form data.  The first approach is making use of the [`name`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Time-cfg-name) property.  This is basically like the `dataIndex` property, but you must use the form's [`loadRecord`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord) method, or some other manual approach, to populate your form field values.

The second approach makes use of the [ViewModel binding](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html)... a new, and powerful, concept in Ext JS 5.  Whenever a change is made to the bound value, then it will update the model's value as well as reflect that value in the UI component.  I encourage you to read the link I provided for the ViewModel binding, as that'll go into a lot more detail.

Comment: Thanks. Let me give a try.